# Good way to run commands on remote computer without its own public-facing IP address (Linux Centos)

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ssh, remote-access

Have a few computers running Linux Centos 6.4. They are connected to an unmanaged switch, which in turn, is connected to a router (Verzion Fios issue).

What is a good way to "log in" to one of the computers so that I can run commands?

- Do I need to use SSH, or something different?
- Since the computers do not have their own public-facing IP addresses, do I need to set up some kind of port forwarding within the router?
- What is a simple, reliable way to accomplish this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Don't forget to yell at Verizon until they give you IPv6, which will eliminate this problem.

Comment: Verizon is so used to me yelling at them that they think I'm just talking normal.

Answer (score 7):

You have a bunch of options, but only two of which are really worth implementing.

1. Configure port forwards for each host's sshd. This way, you'd need to specify a different port when connecting to each.
2. Configure a single port forward to one of the servers and then use that as a "jump host" to get to the other servers. Look into ssh's `ProxyCommand` directive - it can greatly simplify the process of using a jump host.
3. VPN. Since you're using Verizon's router, this may not be an option, but you could implement some sort of VPN (preferrably IPsec or OpenVPN) which you'd connect to and then you'd have access to all of your internal hosts.

In an ideal world, #3 is your best option. However that may not be an option with the router you have. In that case, I'd tend to go with option #2, as it's more simple to manage and it lessens your exposure.

Comment: both sounds like reasonable and easy to implement options, i don't want to bother but what are the other options?

Comment: VPN, getting IP addresses for them, having each server connect out to an outside server so you can tunnel back through...I dunno. How many ways do you want me to come up with? I'm sure I could come up with a few dozen b0rken ways to do this. :)